# trying to click button in Chrome using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

As a newbie writing Macro to automate Chrome (v 75.0.3770.100) using Selenium Basic ChromeDriver (v 75.0.3770.140) in Excel (2013) VBE, I'm trying to find a way to click a button. The id keeps changing. Here's the HTML:

```
<td align="left">
<button type="submit" id="nHuPf" class="login_btn y-btn-primary z-button">Login</button>
</td>
```

I've tried this to no avail:

```
obj.FindElementByClass("login_btn y-btn-primary z-button").Click
```

' The macro starts with this:

```
Dim obj As New ChromeDriver

obj.Start "chrome", "   "
obj.Get "https://sh.com/backoffice"
```

Would appreciate any advice on how to click this button using the Selenium Type Library in Excel VBE, thanks.

Comment: is there an error message?

Comment: I can see `id="nHuPf"` >> so why didn't you try `FindElementByID`?

Comment: the id changes every time the page loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Login** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("button.login_btn.y-btn-primary.z-button[type='submit']").Click
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='login_btn y-btn-primary z-button' and text()='Login']").Click
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Try javascript to execute

```
obj.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector('.login_btn').click();"
```